# Freeze variable False / True to change - make it immutable after first change

Tags: python, if-statement, immutability

hope you can help me out.

Default state of the variable is set to "False" and within the "while True" loop I have "if/else" statement which can change the variable to "True". I would like to keep the variable "True" even the circumstances within the while loop will change in the future.

How can I "freeze" the variable's state? Make it immutable after first one change?

Thanks all who can help.

Comment: I don't think Python has any way to freeze a variable. Why do you change the variable if you don't want to?

Comment: You can create another variable to keep track of this one-time change. If the target variable changed the first time, you set the additional variable to `True` and next time you try to change your target variable, you check this additional variable.

Comment: Please show your code and explain the use case for this.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I do not have code yet but you can "pseudo" consider like this: you have an area where the pointer of mouse should go - default is False, once the pointer come over the state is True, when the mouse move out from the area, the state will remain True even the pointer is not in the area. I'm not sure I explained in the best way but I hope the need is clear.

Comment: you don't need to use an immutable object for that, just stop updating the variable once it's True, or if you need to discriminate between True and immutable True, use a second variable to store the "immutable" state

Comment: TYZ, mozway thx, nice idea, I guess you mean something like this, is that right?

first = False
second = False 

while True:

    if first == True:
        second = True

Comment: @user18845404 I provided 2 examples

Answer (score 0):

```
x = False
while <condition>:
  if <another-condition>:
    x = True
  # ... and do not update x anywhere in the loop
```

Comment: Hi bobah, thx, the point is the "x" still can update within while loop - is there any way to "freeze" it after first change no matter what? thx.

Comment: No way to freeze it. Python does not have immutable references. Could be because one of the cornerstone concepts of Python philosophy is to keep simple things simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the condition once the pointer is in the area and then never change it:

```
pointer_in_area = False

while True:             # main loop
    # move pointer
    if pointer in area: # condition to set the flag
        pointer_in_area = True
    if pointer_in_area:
        # do stuff, now "pointer_in_area" is always True
```

You can further extend this to two variables if you need to track both the current state of the pointer (NOW) and the previous state (was ever in the area):

```
pointer_in_area = False
pointer_once_in_area = False

while True:
    # move pointer
    if pointer in area:
        pointer_in_area = True
        pointer_once_in_area = True
    if pointer_in_area:
        # do stuff that requires pointer to be in area NOW
    if pointer_once_in_area:
        # do other stuff that requires pointer to have been once in area
```